# How does a multi-tenant application fit in Microservices based architecture?

Tags: django, microservices, multi-tenant

I have a SaaS based multi-tenant monolith application (built with Django), that I want to divide into microservices based architecture. But I am not sure how to divide the application into correct partitions. And on what aspects should I take care of?

In case of monolith application, it's easy to understand that I have a tenant model that decides the schemas but how this will be done in microservices if I want each service to be multi-tenant? Or should I even make the services multi-tenant?

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using OAuth and/or generating JWTs for user authentication/authorization, I'd recommend any new services that need tenant scoping to require a user access token be provided in requests just like your Django app. This lets you standardize how credentials and tenant scoping is expected to be passed, and verifying JWTs is a pretty easy process to implement.

That being said, it's also important to point out that you shouldn't require that services use access tokens or have any kind of tenant scoping at all. Not only is it possible that specific services don't require tenant scoping, but it's also possible that they might want to define a tenant differently from the main Django app (e.g. a simple tenant_id). For example, a payments service that only accepts a dollar amount and a credit card doesn't care what the tenant is and would be perfectly safe to call from the main Django application (of course you should prevent public access to the service too).

The best way to think about how new services should be designed is in a vacuum - without care for how other services are designed or how they store their data. Your service was built to perform a task and it defines for itself what parameters it needs to perform that task, how it executes that task, and how it stores the data it needs for future tasks. This independence from the design of other microservices in the stack is part of the power of designing service-oriented systems. It allows creators to pick the right tools for the job, and allows them to create meaningful features without needing to collaborate with dozens of team members that they often don't know.

Hope this helps, and good luck.